Cleaning Vue URL query parameters
I have a Vue application with a checkout view using Stripe.
The js to trigger the Stripe payment is the next one:
await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
                return_url: `${window.location.origin}/account/#/orders/yyyyyy`,
                payment_method_data: {
                    billing_details: billingDetails,
                },
            }
        });

The payment and the redirection are working fine, but the new url include query parameters that the Vue app will keep in following navigations.
Example about the url generated by Stripe: http://xxxxxx/account/?payment_intent=pi_xxxxxx&payment_intent_client_secret=pi_xxxxxx_secret_xxxxxx&redirect_status=succeeded#/orders/yyyyyy
I would like something like http://xxxxxx/account/#/orders/yyyyyy?payment_intent=pi_xxxxxx&payment_intent_client_secret=pi_xxxxxx_secret_xxxxxx&redirect_status=succeeded
But because changing how the url is created by Stripe will be impossible, I would like to remove all the query parameters ?payment_intent=pi_xxxxxx&payment_intent_client_secret=pi_xxxxxx_secret_xxxxxx&redirect_status=succeeded and rewrite the url, so following navigation will be clear again.
NOTE: A would like to avoid refreshing the page.

You are free to modify url at any point and redirect to it, likely router hook, especially since this needs to be done once on router init. If the query part (payment_intent=...) is useful then you need to not just throw it away but process in some way

@EstusFlask But it will refresh the page, right?

That's correct.

@EstusFlask The main problem is that when you navigate to another route, only the part after /#/ changes, and all this query parameters persist in the navigation.

@EstusFlask I try to avoid the refresh, but looks like the only solutions.

Yes, this is why you need to modify location.href on app init when it contains stripe's  query. This doesn't look straightforward but this is how url callbacks from third-party services can work in SPA. Unless you want to let a server to back up client-side routing and handle redirects. Also you can actually try history.replaceState before app init to not interfere with vue router
